# question for free memory in c deleted certain value in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
typedef struct node_t { int val; struct node_t *next; } node;   

node *deleteNumber(node *node, int i) {
    while (node && node->val == i) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    n = node;
    p = node;
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;
    n = n->next;
    while (n) {
        if (n->val == i)
            p->next = n->next;
        else
            p = p->next;
        n = n->next;
    }
    return node;
}
```

I have a question of how to free the memory of deleted node in linked list. The above function, `node` is the linked list I would like to operate on and `int` is the value I would like to delete. Thank you!

It is currently causing valgrind error and I don't know where to start. I have tried free(n,p) but this is not helping

```
> ==1618== 
> ==1618== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==1618==     in use at exit: 192 bytes in 12 blocks
> ==1618==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 0 frees, 192 bytes allocated
> ==1618== 
> ==1618== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==1618==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 8 blocks
> ==1618==    indirectly lost: 48 bytes in 3 blocks
> ==1618==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==1618==    still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==1618==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==1618== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
> ==1618== 
> ==1618== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==1618== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: When you're talking about errors, please, please, **show us the error you're talking about**. We can't see your computer.

Comment: When you delete a node you return an unchanged `node`: suppose you delete the first node? but when you reached the end of the list you `return NULL`. Was the error happening later?

Comment: What is the intended behavior of `deleteNumber`? The actual behavior looks rather strange. It looks like it is trying to remove all nodes from the list where `->val == i`, but that isn't what it is really doing.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your `deleteNumber` is supposed to do, but the following version frees all elements of the list that match the number, returning a pointer to the first element of the remaining list (or `NULL` if the list is now empty).

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t {   int val;   struct node_t *next; } node;

node* deleteNumber(node* start, int i) {
    node* n = start;
    node* p = NULL;
    node* t;

    while (n) {
        t = n;
        n = n->next;
        if (t->val == i) {
            if (p)
                p->next = n;
            else
                start = n;
            free(t);
        } else {
            p = t;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

Here are some additional functions for testing the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* append number to list, returning start of list */
node* addNumber(node* start, int i) {
    node* t;

    t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    if (t == NULL)
        return start;
    t->next = NULL;
    t->val = i;
    if (start) {
        node* p = start;

        while (p->next)
            p = p->next;
        p->next = t;
    } else {
        start = t;
    }
    return start;
}

/* print elements of list */
void printList(node* list) {
    while (list) {
        printf(" %d", list->val);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

/* free whole list */
void deleteList(node* list) {
    node* t;

    while (list) {
        t = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(t);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    const int test[] = { 2, 3, 4, 2, 5 };
    node* start = NULL;
    int i;

    /* construct a list */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]); i++)
        start = addNumber(start, test[i]);
    /* report initial list contents */
    printf("Before:");
    printList(start);
    printf("\n");
    /* delete a number from the list */
    start = deleteNumber(start, 2);
    /* report updated list contents */
    printf("After:");
    printList(start);
    printf("\n");
    /* delete remaining elements of the list to appease Valgrind */
    deleteList(start);
    return 0;
}
```

There should not be any Valgrind errors in the above code.

Comment: For example the linked list is l1 = 2,2,3,4,5 and I input deleteNumber(l1, 2), it supposed to come out like 3,4,5

Comment: @codingmonkeylol What should it do for `l2` = 2,3,3,2,5 and `deleteNumber(l2, 2)`?

Comment: return 3,3,5 but it still has memory leak issue

Comment: ==1650== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1650== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1650== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1650== Command: ./delete
==1650== 
==1650== 
==1650== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1650==     in use at exit: 80 bytes in 5 blocks
==1650==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 7 frees, 192 bytes allocated
==1650== 
==1650== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1650==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 3 blocks
==1650==    indirectly lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks

Comment: @codingmonkeylol Do you free the remaining elements on the list before exiting the program? It says it has lost 3 blocks and there are three elements remaining on the list after you have called deleteNumber. Coincidence?

Comment: @codingmonkeylol I've added some code for a demo program. There should not be any Valgrind errors as it has no leaks.

Comment: I simplified `deleteNumber` a bit, using: `if (p) p->next = n; else start = n;`, because if `p` is `NULL` at that point then it is definitely deleting the start of the list, so `start` definitely needs to change. (Props to @chqrlie for commenting about the exact same change while I was in the middle of editing it!)

Answer (score 0):

In order to `free` the nodes removed from the list, you must save the `next` member before you free the node as you cannot access it once the node is freed.

Here is a modified version:

```
typedef struct node_t { int val; struct node_t *next; } node;   

node *deleteNumber(node *node, int i) {
    node *next, *n, *p;
    while (node && node->val == i) {
        next = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
    if (node != NULL) {
        p = n = node;
        n = n->next;
        while (n) {
            if (n->val == i) {
                next = p->next = n->next;
                free(n);
                n = next;
            } else {
                p = n;
                n = n->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

To avoid code duplication, you can use a more advanced approach with a double pointer:

```
typedef struct node_t { int val; struct node_t *next; } node;   

node *deleteNumber(node *node, int i) {
    node **np = &node;

    while (*np) {
        node *n = *np;
        if (n->val == i) {
            *np = n->next;
            free(n);
        } else {
            np = &n->next;
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```